# Boundary conditions for the $bc$ system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, ghosts

In this question, I will be referring to chapter 2 of Polchinski String Theory vol. 1.

In equation (2.7.29), he states that the boundary conditions for the $bc$ system of the open string are

\begin{equation} c(z)= \tilde{c}(\bar{z}), \quad b(z)= \tilde{b}(\bar{z}), \quad \text{Im}\; z =0. \quad (1)
\end{equation}

$\text{Im} \; z = 0$ is the boundary of the open string, so that, in the cylinder, this should be translated to the the ends of the string: $\sigma_1 = 0$ and $\sigma_1 = \pi$.

Now, the $bc$ system action with the left and right-moving variables reads

$$\int d^2 z \; \big( b \bar{\partial} c + \tilde{b} \partial \tilde{c}\big), $$
with $d^2z = 2 d \sigma_1 d \sigma_2$, $\partial = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_1 - i \partial_2) $, $\bar{\partial} = \frac{1}{2} ( \partial_1 + i \partial_2)$, $0 \leq \sigma_1 \leq \pi$ and $\sigma_2$ being the Euclidean time going from $ - \infty$ to $\infty$.

If I substitute these definitions in the action I get

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} d \sigma_2 \int_0^\pi d\sigma_1 \big(b \partial_1c + i b \partial_2 c + \tilde{b} \partial_1 \tilde{c} - i \tilde{b} \partial_2 \tilde{c} \big).$$

Doing a partial integration in the derivatives with respect to $\sigma_1$, we get the following boundary terms that should be equal to zero

$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} d \sigma_2 \big(bc + \tilde{b} \tilde{c} \big)\bigg\rvert_{\sigma_1=0}^{\sigma_1 = \pi}.$$

As is done in the bosonic string, the boundary conditions at $\sigma_1=0$ and at $\sigma_1 = \pi$ should be zero independently. So that we should have

$$b(z)c(z) + \tilde{b}(\bar{z}) \tilde{c}(\bar{z})=0, \quad \sigma=0 \\
b(z)c(z) + \tilde{b}(\bar{z}) \tilde{c}(\bar{z})=0, \quad \sigma= \pi$$

But these are not the same conditions as in equation (1). Because for the last equations to be satisfied we should have $c(z) = \pm\tilde{c}(\bar{z}) $ and $b(z) = \mp \tilde{b} (\bar{z})$ at $\sigma_1 = 0 , \pi$.

My question is: Does the boundary conditions change in the cylinder or am I doing something wrong?